# serve text/html file with fread() in HTTP response in c

Tags: c, file, http

When building a HTTP response, I need to read the file I want to serve in memory.

For binary files, like `jpeg`, I use

```
//Setup and other headers omitted
stat(file, &fileStat);
int fileSize=fileState.st_size
sprintf(headerBuffer, "content-length: %u\r\n\r\n", fileSize)
fread(fileBuffer, fileSize, 1, filePtr);
//combine headerBuffer and fileBuffer, then send to socket
```

However I don't know how to deal with text files, like `html`. I'm confused about these two things:

- Is the `content-length` still the file size or `strlen(whole file as a string)`? or are they the same thing?
- Can I still use `fread()` to load an text file or do I read it line by line with `fgets()`? I thought `fread()` was only for reading binary files, wasn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Content-length` is the full length of the entity sent in the response. If you're sending a file, it's the file size (unless you're applying any content encoding like gzip, in that case it's the size of the file after encoded).

The concept of "letters" doesn't enter the picture and it wouldn't make sense. HTTP is not used just to transfer text and what constitutes a letter is in itself problematic (e.g. encoding, Unicode version if applicable, ...).

Finally, you can of course, use `fread` instead of `fgets`. There's no reason to send the response line-by-line.

Comment: Sorry, by letters, I mean strlen(whole file as a string). Is it the same as file size for text file?

Comment: @Usa No in general it's not. The file may include bytes with value `0`. Use `fstat` or just count the bytes you've read with `fread`.